# How to have an Amazon like selecting system?

Tags: configurable-product

I want to have the same kind of selection system as Amazon in Magento. This system features; choosing different products and choosing different variants of that product. The most important thing is they are linked to each other so maybe that variant of that product isn't available so it's not viable for choosing. The description and image of the product changes as well when another variant of the product has been chosen. I'm not exactly sure how do this in Magento so I would love to have some help.

[image: The selection system on Amazon.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically nothing more than changing the configurable product dropdown into labels.

This can be done by using swatches for the options with text in the image or using this [Inchoo article](http://inchoo.net/magento/configurable-product-modification-in-magento/).

Basically they change the frontend template `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` to use inputs along with the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` block class

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does unfortunately not change the description or hides unavailable options. Lets say I'm a car seller. I want people to choose between a BMW, Ford and Volkswagen. When the person selects BMW only BMW models appear. The person can choose between the BMW 4 and BMW 5 series. The BMW 4 serie is only available in black and white while the BMW5 is only available in red and green. What I'm trying to say is that the users choices affect further choise options. Like somebody who choose a BMW can't choose a Volkswagen model.

Comment: Ok but splitting up the options in `brand` or `manufacturer` and `model` would do that right? First select the brand, then the `models` applying to the brand are left over

Comment: Yes, it has to be possible to select a variant of different products on 1 page.